# Button element is not getting clicked

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Button's Html

```
<button id="exist_user" onclick="ExtUpdtPnl();" type="button" style="background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);">
<i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i>
Update Existing User
</button>
```

I have used multiple ways as below

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("exist_user")).Click(); 
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]"));
```

Please help..

Comment: Can you post full html code..? or else give some clarity what your getting when you click on the button?

Comment: div id="radAjxPnlDiv">
<div>
<div class="heading">
<h1>User Management</h1>
<div id="rdAjxPnlResultPanel" class="RadAjaxPanel" style="display: block;">
<button id="exist_user" onclick="ExtUpdtPnl();" type="button" style="background-color: rgb(187, 187, 187);">
<button id="add_user" onclick="NewUpdtPnl();" type="button" style="background-color: rgb(241, 242, 242);">
</div>

Comment: Is there any similar id in your html code..? If you have same id having different tag's names, that is also leads to NoSuchElementException. So check **//button[@id='exist_user']** this xpath using firePath.

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.FindElement(By.Id("exist_user")).InvokeMember("click");` instead.

Comment: InvokeMember is not getting supported

Comment: You are using selenium ?
if yes give me the site and the button you want to be clicked and i'll try to see whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try with JavascriptExecutor:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@id='exist_user']"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Or

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('exist_user').click();");
```